# Macros to check cell's value type

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following question. I want to check with macros if a certain cell within range of cells in Excel contains date values (short date i.e. `12.3.2012`) or specific word.

I will try to explain myself with the following example code:

```
Private Sub typedata()
Dim x, y
For x = 12 To 13
 For y = 16 To 71

 If isDate(Cells(x, y)) <> True then
    MsgBox "Please enter correct data"
    Exit Sub
 elseIF Cells(x,y) <> "certain word" Then
    MsgBox "Please enter correct data"
    Exit Sub
 End If

 Next y
Next x
End Sub
```

I will appreciate any help to find the correct code.

Answer (score 1):

First, I suspect (but am not certain) that you have your x's and your y's around the wrong way. The Cells function uses the arguments (Row, Column) and it would be rare to have a really short data range (rows 12 to 13) but a really wide one (columns 16 to 71). (Your code may be right, I'm just noting that it's unusual and something that you may want to check.)

What you're really looking for is the And operator, though one other thing to note is that the certain word test will be case sensitive. I normally therefore compare by converting both to upper case.

Finally, you may want to tell the user where exactly the problem is.

Also I do recommend declaring your variables as a type to avoid the variant to integer conversion cost. I always use Longs rather than integers in VBA (not VB.Net) because Ints get internally converted to longs anyway.

This is quick, dirty and only marginally tested but should point you in the right direction:

```
Private Sub typedata()
Dim x As Long, y As Long
For x = 12 To 13

    For y = 16 To 71

        If IsDate(Cells(x, y)) <> True And UCase(Cells(x, y)) <> UCase("certain word") Then
            MsgBox "Please enter correct data into cell " & Cells(x, y).Address
            Exit Sub
        End If

    Next y
Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: I intentionally set such a short data range because I want to test the Sub only for two rows and when I find the correct code I will use it for complete data range (x = 12 to 69). Unfortunately your suggested code doesn't work :( I still get error message when I enter a short date (i.e. 2.2.2002) or word into the desired cell.

Comment: I assure you that the code DOES work. To begin, you might want to check that 2.2.2002 is in fact a date in terms of your regional settings and is not simply going in as text which YOU recognise as a date, but Excel doesn't. Also it might be an idea to state exactly what the magic word is because you need to obviously change the string expression "certain word" in the code to the actual word that you're using.

Comment: The "certain word" is "delayed" :) The 2.2.2002 is certainly a date because I set Date type for the cells in the desired range.

Comment: I got it :D at last :))  Private Sub typedata()
Dim x, y
brr = 0
For x = 12 To 13
 For y = 16 To 71
 
 
     If Cells(x, y) <> "delayed" And Cells(x, y) <> "" And IsDate(Cells(x, y)) <> True Then
           MsgBox "Error"
           Exit Sub
           
 End If

 Next y
Next x
End Sub

Comment: So essentially the reason that my code "didn't work" is that you've added in an extra condition, unmentioned in the original question, allowing the cells to be empty as well as either a date or a specified word. And incidentally, your code will still generate an error if the user enters "DELAYED" or "Delayed" since, as I mentioned, the check that you have is case sensitive. Oh, and of course, you're welcome.